# Gnome software app data missing in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: gnome-software

Recently i installed Ubuntu 16.04 final beta. but at the first time Gnome software was working perfectly. But suddenly it shows "No Application Data Found". I also checked that packagekit is still there but why it shows no application data found??